# Python, lxml and <type 'exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError'>

Tags: python, unicode, lxml

I am using `lxml` to get a string from a web page.  What do I have to do to get a string of the data that I extract without having the below error? I guess I just can't using `str()` to solve the problem.

In python:

```
mystring = MySQLdb.escape_string(i.text_content())


(<type 'exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError'>, UnicodeEncodeError('ascii', u"\n\nEve Pownall\n\n  \n    \n    \n    \n        Eve Pownall\n\t  (Author)\n\t\n        \u203a Visit Amazon's Eve Pownall Page\n        Find all the books, read about the author, and more.\n\n         See search results for this author  \n        Are you an author?\n        Learn about Author Central\n        \n      \n   \n  \n\n  \n      amznJQ.onReady('bylinePopover', function () {});\n  \n\n\n (Author)\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", 75, 76, 'ordinal not in range(128)'), <traceback object at 0x7f225c99f050>)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808275/decoding-problems-in-django-and-lxml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly encode the string in a good known encoding (UTF-8 most likely).

More info:

http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/troubleshooting/unicode.html

Comment: I hate unicode.  Never understood it.  That was a great link that make things clean how to deal with it.